# Format phone Number including html tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting a phone number including `<strong> </strong>` HTML tags in it. I want to format that phone number into this format `(xxx) xxx-xxxx` including the HTML tags.

For example

```
"7096<strong>95</strong>8048"
```

into:

```
(709) 6<strong>95-</strong>8048
```

Comment: Can the strong tags occur at any arbitrary point of the phone number, or will they always be in the position in your example?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already. (And using a regex is probably overkill, but I don't know enough about your exact spec to be able to say definitely)

Comment: The strong tags will occur randomly between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Have any other special case?

```
var x, r;
x = "7096<strong>95</strong>8048";
r = x.replace(
  /(^\d.*?\d.*?\d)|(<strong>)(.*?)(<\/strong>)/ig,
  function (m, p1,p2,p3,p4) {
    if (p1) return `(${p1}) `;
  else return p2+p3+"-"+p4;
  }
)
console.log(r);
```

On the code above don't care what the user input, the user can input other of number too. Example

`x = "9he3983<STrong>hello367</sTrong>478";`

will be

`"(9he39) 83<STrong>hello368-</sTrong>478"`

If non digit not allowed. In group 1, remove `.*?`; in group 3, replace `.*?` into `\d+`.

Edit:

When I try on regex online, that's cannot use function. I have alternate for this.

```
var x, r;
x = "7096<strong>95</strong>8048";
r = x.replace(
  /(^\d.*?\d.*?\d)(.*?)(<strong>)(.*?)(<\/strong>)/ig,
  "($1) $2$3$4-$5"
)
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a regex replacement:

```js
var input = "7096<strong>95</strong>8048";
var output = input.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d)<strong>(\d{2})<\/strong>(\d{4})$/, "($1) $2<strong>$3-</strong>$4");
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to make a dynamic regEx because I never know were the strong tag will come